Hawking radiation without horizons
According to this Bigthink article which cites this paper all massive objects emit Hawking radiation because they curve spacetime.
But I thought Hawking radiation is the time reversal of a particle falling into a black-hole. Time-reversal is necessary for the laws of thermodynamics to hold; since horizons are perfect absorbers they must also be perfect black-body emitters.
A transparent gas cloud bends spacetime but it cannot absorb light. So how can it emit Hawking radiation? There is no absorption process that can be time-reversed. The article raises similar objections but does not provide a clear answer.

Usually, it's claimed that a horizon is required for Hawking radiation, eg https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304728/123208 But also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/514920/123208

The cited paper relies on another one by the same authors, that has already been discussed on this site. I am quite certain their approach is plain wrong. Note, that non-black hole  stellar remnants in question likely can decay through gravitational channels (e.g. via intermediate virtual black hole states), but calculations for that are strongly from realm of quantum gravity and so are greatly model dependent and cannot be emulated by effective action methods.
